# How to pass different integer arrays to same gallery in the same Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

Here I need to pass images into a gallery.
In one class I have 10 buttons, here when click 1 button I need to pass 1 button related images into the gallery, when click 2 button I need to pass 2 button related images into gallery. 
I tried using the below code but here when click 1 button it is working fine means images displayed into gallery, but when I click 2,3 ...buttons I got black screen.

Please any one suggest me how to pass different arrays into same activity.

```
     HomeDemo.class:
   public class HomeDemo extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
Button home1,home2,home3,home4;
ImageButton back;
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.homedemo);
        home1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        home2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        home3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        home4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        home1.setOnTouchListener(this);
        home2.setOnTouchListener(this);
        home3.setOnTouchListener(this);
        home4.setOnTouchListener(this);
 }
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v==home1)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(HomeDemo.this,Home1.class);
        i.putExtra("k1", 1);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    if(v==home2)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(HomeDemo.this,Home1.class);
        i.putExtra("k2", 2);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    if(v==home3)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(HomeDemo.this,Home1.class);
        i.putExtra("k3", 3);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    if(v==home4)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(HomeDemo.this,Home1.class);
        i.putExtra("k4", 4);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    return false;
}
}

       Home1 .class
       public class Home1 extends Activity implements
          AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory{
       private TextSwitcher mSwitcher;
   ImageButton home,sound;
Gallery g;
static int nextbtn = 0;
static int prebtn = 0;
ImageAdapter iadapter;
int galpos;
int countk1=0;
int countk2=0;
int countk3=0;
int countk4=0;

public int ht;
public int wt;

public static int motiongal = 3000; 
RelativeLayout l1,l2;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.home1);

    home=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.homeimage);
    home.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i=new Intent(Home1.this,HomeDemo.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return false;
        }
    });
     sound=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.soundimage);
      sound.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    ht = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    wt = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
 l1=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
 l2=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear1);
 l1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 l2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        l1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            //Do something after 100ms
              l1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          }
        }, 1500);
        return false;
    }
});


    mSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher);
    mSwitcher.setFactory(this);
    mSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.fade_in));
    mSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.fade_out));
    mSwitcher.startLayoutAnimation();
    try
    {
    g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    g.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    galpos = bundle.getInt("GALPOS");
     countk1 = getIntent().getIntExtra("k1", 0); 
     countk2 = getIntent().getIntExtra("k2", 0); 
     countk3 = getIntent().getIntExtra("k3", 0); 
     countk4 = getIntent().getIntExtra("k4", 0); 

    g.setSelection(galpos);        
    g.setAnimationDuration(motiongal);


    } catch(Exception e){

  }
    g.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


    ImageButton nextButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nextimage);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(nextButtonOnClick);

    ImageButton preButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.preimage);
    preButton.setOnClickListener(preButtonOnClick);



    g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            //Toast.makeText(GalleryActivity.this, "" + mTextNames[position] , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             if(position==12)
            {
                Intent i=new Intent(Home1.this, HomeDemo.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            l1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                //Do something after 100ms
                  l1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              }
            }, 1500);
        }
    });

}



public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    mSwitcher.setText(mTextNames[position]);
    nextbtn = position;



}

public OnClickListener nextButtonOnClick = new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {           

        if(nextbtn < (mTextNames.length-1))
        {     
            try
            {               
            mSwitcher.setText(mTextNames[nextbtn+1]);
            mSwitcher.startLayoutAnimation();               
            mSwitcher.getDrawingTime();
            g.setSelection(nextbtn+1);
            Thread.sleep(300);
            g.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
            g.startLayoutAnimation();
            Thread.sleep(300);
            g.setAnimationDuration(motiongal);  

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {}

        }else
        {
            try
            {               
            mSwitcher.setText(mTextNames[0]);   
            mSwitcher.startLayoutAnimation();               
            mSwitcher.getDrawingTime();
            g.setSelection(0);
            Thread.sleep(300);
            g.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
            g.startLayoutAnimation();
            Thread.sleep(300);
            g.setAnimationDuration(motiongal);                  
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {}
        }

      } 
};   

public OnClickListener preButtonOnClick = new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {           

        if(nextbtn > 0)
        {
            try
            {               

            mSwitcher.startLayoutAnimation();               
            mSwitcher.getDrawingTime();
            g.setSelection(nextbtn-1);
            Thread.sleep(300);
            g.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
            g.startLayoutAnimation();
            Thread.sleep(300);
            g.setAnimationDuration(motiongal);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {}


        }else
        {
            try
            {               
            mSwitcher.setText(mTextNames[mTextNames.length-1]);
            mSwitcher.startLayoutAnimation();               
            mSwitcher.getDrawingTime();
            g.setSelection(mTextNames.length-1);
            Thread.sleep(300);
            g.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
            g.startLayoutAnimation();
            Thread.sleep(300);
            g.setAnimationDuration(motiongal);                  
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {}

        }

      } 
};    


public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}

public View makeView() {
    TextView i = new TextView(this);
    i.setTextSize(18);

    i.setGravity(1);
    return i;
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mPhotos.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
       if(countk1==1)
       {
        i.setImageResource(mPhotos.get(position));
       }
       if(countk2==1)
       {
        i.setImageResource(mPhotos1.get(position));
       }
       if(countk2==3)
       {
        i.setImageResource(mPhotos1.get(position));
       }
       if(countk2==4)
       {
        i.setImageResource(mPhotos1.get(position));
       }

        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(
               LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        return i;
    }

    private Context mContext;

}


private boolean isScrollingLeft(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2){
      return e2.getX() > e1.getX();
    }

    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY){
      int kEvent;
      if(isScrollingLeft(e1, e2)){ //Check if scrolling left
        kEvent = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT;
      }
      else{ //Otherwise scrolling right
        kEvent = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT;
      }
      onKeyDown(kEvent, null);
      return true;  
    }


private Integer[] mImageIds = {
         R.drawable.bokstavslottet01,
         R.drawable.bokstavslottet02,
         R.drawable.bokstavslottet03,
         R.drawable.bokstavslottet04,
         R.drawable.bokstavslottet05,
         R.drawable.bokstavslottet06,
         R.drawable.bokstavslottet07,
         R.drawable.bokstavslottet08,
         R.drawable.bokstavslottet09,
         R.drawable.bokstavslottet10,
         R.drawable.bokstavslottet11,
         R.drawable.bokstavslottet12,
         R.drawable.bokstavslottet13
        };

private Integer[] mImageIds1 = {
     R.drawable.i1,
        R.drawable.i2,
        R.drawable.i3,
        R.drawable.i4,
        R.drawable.i5,
        R.drawable.i6,
        R.drawable.i7,
        R.drawable.i8,
        R.drawable.i9,
        R.drawable.i10,
        R.drawable.i11,
        R.drawable.i12,
        R.drawable.i13
    };

private static String[] mTextNames = {
"BOOKSTOVEN1", "BOOKSTOVEN2", "BOOKSTOVEN3", "BOOKSTOVEN4", "BOOKSTOVEN5", "BOOKSTOVEN6", "BOOKSTOVEN7", "BOOKSTOVEN8", "BOOKSTOVEN9", "BOOKSTOVEN10", "BOOKSTOVEN11", "BOOKSTOVEN12", "BOOKSTOVEN13"};



private ArrayList<Integer> mPhotos = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(mImageIds));
private ArrayList<Integer> mPhotos1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(mImageIds1));

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.First thing i wish to ask with you is, You mentioned here for 1 `mPhotos` array and for remaining three `mPhotos1`. If you went right in this code means why you need unnecessary `if` conditions, you can put else for the first `if` and supply the `mPhotos1` array for remaining (Or other wise you dont need to supply the 2,3,4 values).

1. Next one is you did a mistake here at `if(countk2==1)`. how it will be possible to compare, because you only pass `2` for the `k2` extra.

   ```
   if(countk1==1)
      {
       i.setImageResource(mPhotos.get(position));
      }
      if(countk2==1)
      {
       i.setImageResource(mPhotos1.get(position));
      }
      if(countk2==3)
      {
       i.setImageResource(mPhotos1.get(position));
      }
      if(countk2==4)
      {
       i.setImageResource(mPhotos1.get(position));
      }
   ```
2. Then, i think you dont need to put Extra values with different names in the following code.

Here you are receiving `k1`, `k2`,`k3`,`k4` values independently. I feel that you dont need to do this.

```
     countk1 = getIntent().getIntExtra("k1", 0); 
     countk2 = getIntent().getIntExtra("k2", 0); 
     countk3 = getIntent().getIntExtra("k3", 0); 
     countk4 = getIntent().getIntExtra("k4", 0);





if(v==home1)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(HomeDemo.this,Home1.class);
        i.putExtra("k1", 1);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    if(v==home2)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(HomeDemo.this,Home1.class);
        i.putExtra("k2", 2);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    if(v==home3)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(HomeDemo.this,Home1.class);
        i.putExtra("k3", 3);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    if(v==home4)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(HomeDemo.this,Home1.class);
        i.putExtra("k4", 4);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Instead of doing the above, you can `putExtra` for the intent like the following code.

```
if(v==home1)
{
    Intent i=new Intent(HomeDemo.this,Home1.class);
    i.putExtra("k", 1);
    startActivity(i);
}
if(v==home2)
{
    Intent i=new Intent(HomeDemo.this,Home1.class);
    i.putExtra("k", 2);
    startActivity(i);
}
if(v==home3)
{
    Intent i=new Intent(HomeDemo.this,Home1.class);
    i.putExtra("k", 3);
    startActivity(i);
}
if(v==home4)
{
    Intent i=new Intent(HomeDemo.this,Home1.class);
    i.putExtra("k", 4);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

And then you can receive like the following code,

```
     count = getIntent().getIntExtra("k", 0);
```

And in the `Adapter` you can follow this,

```
   if(count==1)
   {
    i.setImageResource(mPhotos.get(position));
   }
   else if(count==2)
   {
    i.setImageResource(mPhotos1.get(position));
   }
   else if(count==3)
   {
    i.setImageResource(mPhotos2.get(position));
   }
   if(count==4)
   {
    i.setImageResource(mPhotos3.get(position));
   }
```

I hope that you have understand the above explanation.

And here are some useful solutions.

For receiving the `Extras`
You can do like the following also,

`getIntent.getIntExtrta("k",0)` without using `Bundle`.

Comment: If its the problem with getting `Extra` values means, Here you are not necessarily required to pass `Integer` values right. So do one thing instead of 1,2,3,4. use some `Text` values like "A", "B", "C", "D". then pass this String `Extras`. it will works i am 100% assure. In some cases `Integer` `Extras` have same problems.

Comment: Dude thats happy to hear you got worked it out. But you must need to share your solutions. Like where you went wrong and what are the things you have changed in the code.  So that only others can easily knows the solution for this kind of problem. I think that is the purpose why we are sharing here. Its not for your gain. And by optional if u feel this answer helpful pls vote them UP to cheers with it. Hope you got it dude...

Comment: hi here mPhotos having having 13 images,and mPhotos1 having 16 images when i displyed mPhotos1  array images that time only 13 images  displyed scrolled,14 image onwords not displyed..

Answer (score 0):

Set your activity to implement OnClickListener instead of OnTouchListener

Comment: thankyou for your response.but treid using onclicklistener also but i am getting same problem

Comment: getView has if(countk2==1) this should be if(countk2==2)

Comment: ok i gave.but same prblm.but i think prblm is... in getcount() i gave   return mPhotos.size();.but in if(countk2==2) in this condition i gave  i.setImageResource(mPhotos1.get(position));

Comment: but in getcount() i gave return mPhotos.size(); means only 1 button working, if i gave return mPhotos1.size(); means only 2 button working, so now what i need to do u have any idea suggest me

Comment: There are plenty of small issues but fix for getCount is like if(countk1==1) return mPhotos.size() else if (countk2==2) return mPhotos1.size() etc.

Comment: Then you need just need to repeat the behavior in countk3 and countk4 cases, you need 2 more arrays for images and so on

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10167/discussion-between-niko-and-user1105975)

Comment: public int getCount() {
   if(countk1==1)
   {
    return mPhotos.size();
   }
   else
    
    if(countk2==2)
    {
     return mPhotos1.size();
    }
        } i treid this way but here i am getting error

Comment: Join the chat by clicking the "continue this discussion in chat"

Comment: Well that exactly what i said, didn't just give straight code to copy paste :)